# How to use servlet contextPath with PropertySource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to load a configuration file that has the same name as the contextPath. Here is the code I tried:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${user.home}/#{servletContext.contextPath}.properties")
public class PropertiesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

The above code does not work because `#{servletContext.contextPath}` is not resolved.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that `servletContext` is not accessible in `@PropertySource`. A workaround is to use `@Value` to get the contextPath value.

```dart
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer(
            @Value("#{servletContext.contextPath}") String contextPath) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocation(new UrlResource("file:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + contextPath + ".properties"));
        return configurer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/my.properties")
public class MyConfig {
 public @Value("#{ servletContext.getContextPath() }") String test;
 }
```

- Try this

Comment: Thanks, indeed I can retrieve the value with `@Value`. Strange that it doesn't work directly in `@PropertySource`